# `The property Hashtags is valid only for Exchange Exchange2015 or later versions.' when `EmailMessage.Bind`

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, hashtag

My Outlook add-in uses `Office.js` to get the EWS token and send it to the backend to bind to get the required Info.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
                service.Url = new Uri(mailItem.ewsUrl);
                service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(mailItem.ewsToken);
                _email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(mailItem.itemID));
                return _email;
```

However, I get this error throwns by this line `_email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(mailItem.itemID));`

The issue is when I use `EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(mailItem.itemID));` EWS will load all the `FirstClassProperties` to me(some of them I do not event need it) It there a way to return only limited fields of `FirstClassProperties`

Answer (score 2):

When I call `_email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(mailItem.itemID));`
EWS will return me a predefined set of properties `FirstClassProperties`.
Although `hashtag` does not belong to `FirstClassProperties`, but that call somehow tries to retrieve that field. So instead of loading a bunch of stuff which I do not need all, I only ask for those I need.

```
PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(
                                                ItemSchema.Subject,
                                                ItemSchema.InReplyTo,
                                                ItemSchema.Body,
                                                ItemSchema.DateTimeSent,
                                                ItemSchema.DisplayTo,
                                                ItemSchema.Importance,
                                                EmailMessageSchema.From,
                                                ItemSchema.UniqueBody, 
                                                ItemSchema.MimeContent, 
                                                ItemSchema.HasAttachments, 
                                                ItemSchema.Attachments
                                                );
_email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(mailItem.itemID),ps);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your mentioned, the error only occurs with specific email. You could refer to the following link:

[C# Exchange Service suddenly giving error The property Hashtags is valid only for Exchange Exchange2015 or later versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519985/c-sharp-exchange-service-suddenly-giving-error-the-property-hashtags-is-valid-on)

Unfortunately, I didn't find any information about Hashtags property of Exchange. However, can we use the "Try Catch" code block to ignore the issue?

Comment: I think a better way would be to ask EWS specifically for what I need..then I can safely exclude properties like `hashTag` that I know I will never need it